# How to serve views from the Cloudfront CDN

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, handlebars.js, amazon-cloudfront

The only reason I am using cloudfront is to limit my website to United States users. I have already whitelisted the US as a country in the cloudfront settings. I would like the whole website to not be shown outside of US; ideally some 303 redirect or a message that this website is not available in your country would be displayed to other users.

Both images below show on my website. How do I make the views be served from the cloudfront as well? Maybe I am thinking of this wrong, but I am not sure how to restrict the whole website as opposed to just the images.

```
<p><img src="http://d2nprsvqt0000.cloudfront.net/img/demo.png" alt="my test image">
<p><img src="/img/demo.png" alt="my demo">

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('about');
});
```

Comment: you have a website running on node? and only html/css static content is served through cloudfront?

Comment: Yes, it's running on node/ubuntu/nginx/EC2. I have a test page with two images, one with a cloudfront url and one with /img/demo.png served from my public folder. When I use a VPN to simulate different countries, only the one served from my /public/img folder is shown. Which is what I would expect. But I want the whole website to not show outside the US. I can only block the static content it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Serve your website through CloudFront, with two origins. One for S3 assets, the other for your app.

See [Dynamic Whole Site Delivery with Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamic-whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront/).

Comment: I'm not using S3, my origin is my EC-2 server.

Comment: Are you using Route 53? You would typically use Route53 to create an alias that points to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: I am using Route53 but I didn't manage to point it to the CloudFront distribution, don't know how, I tried creating an alias but it didn't work.

Comment: Did this not help (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)?

Comment: I created now a AAAA alias because IP6 is enabled and had the alias target to my cloudfront.net distribution. I already had an A alias which points to my example.com domain. I've checked my website through a vpn and it's still accessible from other countries. Do I need to delete my simple A alias that goes to example.com?

Comment: I have type A IPv4 Alias yes, with name www.example.com and type AAAA alias Yes name example.com. They both point to the d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net distribution. The only change that did was to redirect traffic from www.example.com to 403 ERROR Generated by cloudfront. Going to example.com works fine.